# equivalent of Chrome sandbox keyword inside Firefox manifest v3 browser extension

Tags: firefox-addon, manifest, sandbox, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I created a Chrome extension with manifest v3, one of the pages needs to execute eval in order to run a script. Inside the manifest I defined the keyword:

```
"sandbox": {
    "pages": ["custom_page.htm"]
},
```

In this way the page *custom_page.htm* can execute eval and the extension works.

I am porting this extension to Firefox (manifest v3) and I can't find an equivalent of the *sandbox* keyword, I tried adding the *content_security_policy* keyword ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy)) but I always get the error

```
call to eval() blocked by CSP
```

Is it possible to execute eval inside a firefox extension?

Comment: Evidently it's not yet implemented.